# Memcpy and const correctness

Tags: c++, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

When using cppcheck on my code it indicated a function could be made const. Cppcheck seems to be correct but I found the memcpy in the code strange.

Excerpt from the code:

```
 if ( (offset + size) <= _bufferSize )
        {
            char* _destPtr = (char*)_buffer + offset;
            memcpy(_destPtr, data, size);
            result = true;
        }
```

To my understanding the memcpy will indirectly write to _buffer so the function is not const. However even when using _buffer directly the compiler still compiles the code without an error.

Why does the compiler not generate an error here?

Comment: Hard to tell if you don't post the function signature and where cppcheck wants you to place the `const`. Please create a [MCVE].

Comment: It's modifying things pointed by `_buffer`, not `_buffer` itself; then it could be `const` function.

Comment: You are using a C-style cast, which basically means you know better than your compiler and it needs to shut up and do what you are telling it. If you want your tools to typecheck your code for you, consider not using C-style casts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different places where `const` can be used with pointers.

```
 const char * x;  // (1) data pointed by x is const
 char * const x;  // (2) x itself is const
```

Making your object `const` makes its pointer-type members `const` in the second sense, never in the first sense. The current object (`*this`) is `const` in a `const` member function.

If you need the pointed-to data become `const` too, you can wrap your pointers in a custom class that does deep propagation of constness:

```
template <class T> class deep_const_ptr {
     // .... ctors, operator*, the usual stuff
     T* get() { return data; }
     const T* get() const { return data; }
  private:
     T* data;
};
```